# How to maintain data in attribute table when importing ASCII file to ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, import, ascii

I am very new to using ArcGIS. I have an Excel sheet with data in it where each cell represents a grid from a model output and contains a value (eg. amount of precipitation in that grid cell from the model output). I have taken the data and put it into ASCII format in order to import it to ArcMap. The data appears to import and display correctly on the map, but the attribute table does not maintain the original model out put values (eg. precipitation and location). Is there a way to change the attribute table to better reflect the data and get it in a format similar to what I started with? I will use these numbers later on for further analysis.

Below is a screen shot containing the map view, attribute table, and original text file that I imported.

[image: Below is a screen shot containing the map view, attribute table, and original text file that I imported.]

Comment: Looking at your screen shot I would say the attribute table is correct, you have for example 5 cells with a value of 5. In the context of a raster the attribute table is a "summary" of the number of cells for value "X".

Comment: But why/how did it decide to just do the "summary"? How can I get an attribute table that maintains the information that I started with? For example... maybe giving each cell/block/grid/square an ID number and a value associated with it. I will need these values later on in other analysis, but I don't need to know the total number of times "5" showed up as a value...

Answer (score 1):

It didn't just decide to do the "summary"; that's how you submitted it.

It depends on your ultimate goal with the data, but you have at least a couple options:

- Create one raster for each attribute of interest. My suspicion is that this is what you should do, because I've never encountered a reason to use option 2...

or

- Create another column in your input table and populate it with unique values for each unique combination of values from your columns of interest, and then use that new column as your value column when creating the raster. Later, [join that table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/joining-tables-to-your-raster-attribute-table.htm) to your raster attribute table.